# Passing parameter value is not getting

Tags: asp.net

Iam passing a parameter in response.redirect,But the value is not getting on the target page

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender,
                      System.EventArgs e)
{
 string umasterid = drow["UserMasterId"].ToString();
 Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Name=" + umasterid );
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string Name = Request.QueryString["Name"];//value not getting here
    }
```

what went wrong for me???

Comment: are you sure umasterid contains value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

Login.aspx

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender,System.EventArgs e)
{     
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Name=umasterid");
}
```

Default.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Response.Write(Request.QueryString["Name"]);     
}
```